# Executing javascript function, which name is stored in variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have HTML tag where i am storing the function name to be called in a attribute.

```
<div id="it3" evt="swipeleft|swiperight" act="evtsheet['it2L']|evtsheet['it3R']" class="focusable off" style="width: 25%; height: 26.031746031746035%; top: 60.63492063492063%; left: 44.82142857142858%; z-index: 998; "></div>
<div id="it4" evt="swipeleft|swiperight" act="evtsheet['it3L']|evtsheet['it4R']" class="focusable off" style="width: 25%; height: 25.709325396825395%; top: 60.952380952380956%; left: 60.357142857142854%; z-index: 999; ></div>
```

And also i have this script.

```
<script>
    var evtsheet = {
        it2L : function(){/*some code*/}
        it3L : function(){/*some code*/}
        it3R : function(){/*some code*/} 
        it4L : function(){/*some code*/}
        /*have more similar functions*/
    }
</script>
```

Lets consider this HTML/JS is in index.html Now, I have a wrapper.js where am accessing the above element and getting the function name.
example:

```
com.xxx.init = function(ele){       //ele = "#it3"

     var e = ($(ele).attr("act")).split("|");   
     // e is array with values e[0] = evtsheet['it2L'] and 
     //                        e[1] = evtsheet['it3R']

     //Here i need to invoke the function
     //             ?????
```

}

How can i invoke the function evtsheet['it3R'] ??

Comment: How you tried `evtsheet['it3L']();`

Answer (score 1):

The function reference is just a property on the object. In JavaScript, you can access object properties in *two* ways:

1. Using dotted notation and a literal property name: `obj.foo`
2. Using bracketed notation and a string property name: `obj["foo"]`

In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression.

Once you've accessed the property, you just add `()` to call it.

So:

```
evtsheet['it3L']();
```

or

```
evtsheet.it3L();
```

With either of those, within the call, `this` will be `evtsheet`.

You said

> I could able to access this value and store in a variable.

You can do that, like this:

```
var f = evtsheet['it3L'];
```

or

```
var f = evtsheet.it3L;
```

and then call it:

```
f();
```

but note that if you do that, `this` will *not* be `evtsheet` within the call. (It will be the global object or `undefined`, depending on whether you're in strict mode.)

More:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

Re getting the names from the HTML. I would change them to look like this so they're easier to grab (they're not *hard* the way you have it, but they're easier like this):

```
<div id="it3" evt="swipeleft|swiperight" act="evtsheet.it2L|evtsheet.it3R" class="focusable off" style="width: 25%; height: 26.031746031746035%; top: 60.63492063492063%; left: 44.82142857142858%; z-index: 998; "></div>
<div id="it4" evt="swipeleft|swiperight" act="evtsheet.it3L|evtsheet.it4R" class="focusable off" style="width: 25%; height: 25.709325396825395%; top: 60.952380952380956%; left: 60.357142857142854%; z-index: 999; ></div>
```

So then you can use `split` to get the parts of it:

```
com.xxx.init = function(ele) {       //ele = "#it3"

     var e = $(ele).attr("act").split("|");

     // This assumes `evtsheet` is a global variable
     // Here's how to call the function defined by `e[0]`:
     var parts = e[0].split('.');
     window[parts[0]][parts[1]]();

     // (And you can generalize it for any of the other functions in
     // the `e` array)
}
```

That assumes `evtsheet` is a global variable (which it is in your question). I don't like global variables, so I'd probably put all of the code in a scoping function (to avoid creating globals) and do this:

```
<script>
    // Start the scoping function
    (function() {
        // Make evtsheet a property of an object
        var stuff = {
            evtsheet: {
                it2L : function(){/*some code*/},
                it3L : function(){/*some code*/},
                it3R : function(){/*some code*/},
                it4L : function(){/*some code*/},
               /*have more similar functions*/
            }
        };

        // ...other stuff...

        com.xxx.init = function(ele) {       //ele = "#it3"

             var e = $(ele).attr("act").split("|");

             // We no longer assume `evtsheet` is a global, but it *is*
             // a property on `stuff`.
             // Here's how to call the function defined by `e[0]`:
             var parts = e[0].split('.');
             stuff[parts[0]][parts[1]]();

             // (And you can generalize it for any of the other functions in
             // the `e` array)
        };


        // ...other stuff...

    // End of scoping function
    })();
</script>
```

If you want to keep the names the same as they are, it's a fairly simple regex instead:

```
var parts = /^([^[]+)['([^']+)']$/.exec(e[0]);
if (parts) {
    stuff[parts[1]][parts[2]](); // Note the indexes changed
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, it says Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Comment: @SrikanthKshatriy: Then you're not doing the above correctly, or your `evtsheet` isn't as you've shown. It does work: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uwukez/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uwukez/1/edit)

Comment: @Crowder: i saw a your example. absolutely it will work there. but here am getting function name from the html attribute. let me elaborate the question on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function in the following way

```
<script>
    var evtsheet = {
        it3L : function() {
            console.log("test")
        }

    }
    evtsheet['it3L']();        
    // evtsheet.it3L();
</script>
```

Comment: I guess u didnt get my question

Comment: I guess nobody get your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the name of the function instead:

```
//assuming that you are going to get the "act" property and parse it
<div id="it3" act="it3L|it4R"...

//get the function name, for example, it3L
var evt = 'it3L';

//execute that function from your evtsheet object
evtsheet[evt].call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for events. Events are a way to call functions when something happens. Now, you did not specify when do you want to call those functions, let's take one of the most common for example: onClick.

```
<div id="it3" evt="swipeleft|swiperight" onclick="funcName()" ...></div>
```

And the script

```
<script>
    function funcName() {
        // Anything goes...
    }
</script>
```

Also, if you want to store metainformation in html tags, I suggest you to use the standard data- attributes, see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute